# Properly Create Multiple Event Listeners using a Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, addeventlistener

I'm trying to prepend old messages to a chatbox when the user scrolls to the top. I'm using eventListeners as the code illustrates, but I'm running into an error where only the last chatbox is working properly. It seems that it's only using the most recent i-value as opposed to the i-value it should be using when the eventListener is first created. How do I fix this issue?

Edit: Using index for the eventListeners solved that issue. But it seems the problem was something else; bodies[0].scrollTop always return 0 even when the chatBox is scrolled on.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.popup-messages').forEach((item, index) =>
{   
    item.addEventListener('scroll', async function()
    {
        console.log(index);
        console.log(bodies[index].scrollTop);
        if (chatReady[index] == true && bodies[index].scrollTop == 0)
        {
            chatReady[index] = false;
            var previousHeight = bodies[index].scrollHeight;
                    
            await getMessages(item.id.replace(":body", ""));
                    
            var heightDiff = bodies[index].scrollHeight - previousHeight;
            bodies[index].scrollTop += heightDiff;
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: try `let i = Number(counter);` to have `i` holding a number instead of a reference to the same number as `counter`, which gets incremented.

Comment: Doesn't work, thanks for the attempt.

Comment: `let i = parseInt(counter);` then?

Comment: `forEach()` gives you the index for free `.forEach((item, index) => ...`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette primitive values aren't stored as references.

Comment: chatReady is a global array. index actually works properly (just checked). It seems the problem is something else. bodies[0].scrollTop is always 0 even though bodies[1].scrollTop's value correctly changes. I'll post more code.

Comment: and @pilchard 's suggestions doesn't work?

Comment: Index works, but there might've been another issue in the code. bodies[0] always returns 0 even when I scroll on its associated chatBox.

Comment: All bodies[index].scrollTop always return 0 except for the bodies element associated with the last index. That said I tried console.log(index) for the scroll events and it logs the correct index for the chatbox. I also tried console.log(bodies[index]) and it returns the correct div element.

Comment: I changed back the code, because I don't think the issue lies outside the eventListeners.